24.04 installation screen goes blank
i've tried to install 24.04 server on an acer aspire m5811 desktop. 22.04 is running without any issues on this box but i'd still like to benefit from the improvements which come with 24.04. the display of the installer for 24.04 goes blank shortly after having selected "try or install" and i never get to see the screen where the language needs to be selected. this applies to ubuntu server but i am facing the same issue also with the desktop version - not even the "save graphics" mode resolves the issue. i also tried to re-install 22.04.5 what still works perfectly fine while i don't seem to get 24.04 running on this hardware. the nvidia graphics card of this box has been removed long time ago so i am using the onboard vga controller. lshw -c video output from the 22.04 installation:
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 12
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:33 memory:fb800000-fbbfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:cc00(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff

any suggestions/hints how i could get 24.04 running on this system?

This question is similar to: Installation problem zotac zbox en1060. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've been using Ubuntu for 14 years and 24.04 is the biggest and most time consuming install by far. I had the same issue using 'Startup Disk Creator' and 'UnetBootin'. However, I installed Balena Etcher to burn the ISO file and it worked perfectly. It can take 5 to 10 minutes to load after the  'Try Ubuntu Menu' and then the install can take an hour. Patience is a must when installing 24.04. I also recommend using a 16gb USB drive to burn the ISO because the system files are almost 8gb. Hope this helps.
https://etcher.balena.io/

just found the following posting: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/blank-screen-after-try-or-install-ubuntu/50880.
adding "nomodeset acpi=off" resolved the issue described in here and the ubuntu 24.04 server installation went through smoothly.

adding "nomodeset" would have been sufficient to resolve the issue described in here. just learnt that due to the additional acpi=off parameter the shutdown of the system stopped with the power switched on so i removed the acpi parameter again and everything works fine. see here for a very helpful explanation of these kernel parameters: What do the nomodeset, quiet and splash kernel parameters mean?
